# Python get a list of cities, states, region

Tags: python, list, geolocation, timezone

I have a dataframe that contains a column of cities. I am looking to match the city with its region. For example, **San Francisco** would be **West**.

Here is my original dataframe:

```
data = {'city': ['San Francisco', 'New York', 'Chicago', 'Philadelphia', 'Boston'], 
    'year': [2012, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2014], 
    'reports': [4, 24, 31, 2, 3]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data, index = ['Cochice', 'Pima', 'Santa Cruz', 'Maricopa', 'Yuma'])
df

city           year   reports
San Francisco  2012   Cochice
New York       2012   Pima
Chicago        2013   Santa Cruz
Philadelphia   2014   Maricopa
Boston         2014   Yuma
```

Here I pull data that contains region by state. However, it does not contain city.

```
pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/cphalpert/census-regions/master/us%20census%20bureau%20regions%20and%20divisions.csv')
```

How do I get the state per city? That way I can then join the original dataframe including state with the second dataframe that has region.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On [this Github project](https://github.com/grammakov/USA-cities-and-states) there is a CSV that the creator claims to contain all American cities and states.

The following data is presented:

```
City|State short name|State full name|County|City Alias Mixed Case
```

Example:

```
San Francisco|CA|California|SAN FRANCISCO|San Francisco
San Francisco|CA|California|SAN MATEO|San Francisco Intnl Airport
San Francisco|CA|California|SAN MATEO|San Francisco
San Francisco|CA|California|SAN FRANCISCO|Presidio
San Francisco|CA|California|SAN FRANCISCO|Bank Of America
San Francisco|CA|California|SAN FRANCISCO|Wells Fargo Bank
San Francisco|CA|California|SAN FRANCISCO|First Interstate Bank
San Francisco|CA|California|SAN FRANCISCO|Uc San Francisco
San Francisco|CA|California|SAN FRANCISCO|Union Bank Of California
San Francisco|CA|California|SAN FRANCISCO|Irs Service Center
San Francisco|CA|California|SAN FRANCISCO|At & T
San Francisco|CA|California|SAN FRANCISCO|Pacific Gas And Electric
Sacramento|CA|California|SACRAMENTO|Sacramento
Sacramento|CA|California|SACRAMENTO|Ca Franchise Tx Brd Brm
Sacramento|CA|California|SACRAMENTO|Ca State Govt Brm
```

I suggest you parse the above file to extract the info you need (on this case, the state given a specific city) then you correlate with the region on the other csv you have.

Better still would be for you to create your own table using all the csvs you access to contain only the info you really need.